# If I re-scale my input range for differential input to ADC, can I double resolution?

Tags: adc

I'm just building my first separate ADC circuit, after deciding Arduino was limiting me too much / it is just time to start understanding how to do things properly.

I currently am using a [LT1290 ADC](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1290fe.pdf) with a [LT1027](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1027fcs.pdf) 5V reference. I have essentially stuck to exactly the example circuit given in the data sheet to get started, it is what I need anyway. I am currently sticking with single-inputs.

I was just wondering if by re-scaling my input signal from 0to5V to -5Vto+5V, and feeding this in as a differential input, is this an easy way of doubling the resolution (2 x 4096)? Or is there a high price to pay in accuracy compared to the increased complexity of the needed circuit?

Thanks

Comment: The first question to ask here is why do you need more resolution? Do you really need it? And second, what kind of signal are you sampling? Give us a clear picture of what you want to do so we can better assist you. As it looks, you might have the wrong hardware.

Comment: I'm sampling a new strain sensor that I haven't calibrated yet using a standard voltage divider. I know how to choose the correct resistor values for that, and I think I'm clear on how to use op-amps correctly to make sure I'm sticking to the full range of available input values. I usually have voltage divider across 5V into analog input on Arduino, and leave it at that.

Comment: I might not need more resolution, you're right. It's very possible, the sensor is just too noise anyway, I was querying this as wanted to know if I had understood correctly, so I know if this might be an option in the future.

Comment: Why do you think I have the wrong hardware in the first place, that worries me a lot more than my actual question?

Comment: Well, if the example circuit *is what you need*, then adding a negative rail to use an unnecessary differencial input is a *high price to pay*. Whatever cost/benefit you application will have cannot be speculated on with the information currently present on your question.

Comment: I see. I was working out a good circuit, then when I chose the LT1290, one of the application examples was for an 8-channel 12 bit sampling data acquisition system, with a nice precision voltage regulator which is what I wanted anyway, so I thought best to go with that, at least to get me going, so I know at least I have a circuit that has been designed correctly to start with.

Comment: OK, it is unnecessary to add the differential then. Maybe later down the line, I will think about it, and work out if there is any benefit once I know more. From what I gather I don't get particularly bad noise from any long cables etc currently which I have read can be helped with differential and twisted cables, this might change in the future though. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will get 12-bit resolution in either case.

The codes for unipolar operation

[image]

and bipolar operation can be found in the datasheet

[image]

And you can see that for bipolar operation the LSB changes from 1.2mV to 2.4mV. So there is no increase in resolution, just a different scaling.

Comment: This is great information, thanks! I suspected that something along these lines might be the case, but  just didn't know how /where the error might show itself, I'm still at a point where it is hard to check stuff, I just don't know quite what question to ask! This is very clear, thankyou!

Comment: I'm too lowly to actually upvote you yet sorry!

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about the resolution of an ADC, you are talking about the number of bits actually. So a 12 bit ADC is a 12 bit ADC and unless otherwise stated in the datasheet, it will remain a 12 bit ADC whatever your input range is.

However, by doubling the input range, you are actually doubling the step size of the ADC.

I'm not sure if this is a good or bad thing for you because this really depends

Comment: Great, thankyou, doubling the stepsize, really helpful seeing people explain it slightly differently.

Comment: I'm too lowly to actually upvote you, sorry!